# How to say the phrase in text in a formal way

Tags: phrase-request, formal

I would like to contact the manager of a company and ask a question like :

Hello Mr. ...

I would like to hear from you about your idea on the offer we made to you last week.

what would be a formal phrasing of it ? I know anyway how to say it in Italian but I am searching for more appropriate ways.

The phrase I immagine is :

Le vorrei sentire la sua opinione sulla offerta che vi abbiamo fatto la settimana scorsa.

Comment: We cannot translate something for you here. Check [this](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/is-asking-to-translate-a-short-paragraph-from-english-to-italian-on-topic-here) on Meta. However, if you provide an Italian sentence and explain your doubts about it, somebody will be glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

I think that a good one can be

> Gradirei sentire la sua opinione in merito all'offerta che le abbiamo fatto la scorsa settimana

I suggest you to don't use "ciao" since as translation of "hello" since it isn't formal. Use instead "salve" (it's good in a lot of situations) or "buongiorno"/"buonasera".

Comment: In an effort to be formal, it would be even better to begin a letter or message with “Egregio sig./dott./... [Surname]”, rather than “buongiorno/buonasera”, which is frowned upon by some as a formula to begin a written communication.

Comment: Non ho suggerito l'uso di "egregio" o simili forme di cortesia perché, pur avendo specificato il contesto formale, ha cercato una traduzione per "hello Mr.". Da quanto ne so, "hello" può essere usato in un contesto più formale rispetto al "ciao" ma non credo si possa usare in contesti in cui in italiano si userebbe una forma di cortesia come "egregio".

Comment: Personalmente, a una persona con cui sono solo in contatto per lavoro o affari, come minimo scrivo “gentile”. Ho sentito personalmente professionisti  sghignazzare o arricciare il naso per un “buongiorno / buonasera / salve” in una comunicazione scritta. In più, la distinzione classica era “gentile” se l'interlocutore è una donna ed “egregio” se è un uomo.

Comment: Trovo giusto il tuo punto di vista e lo condivido. Per quanto riguarda la distinzione classica tra i due sessi, credo sia un bene abbandonarla. ;)